# Junit parameterized test

Tags: java, junit, junit4, data-modeling

Trying to model some data for a parameterized junit test but am having trouble understanding how to make it actually work.  The data I am trying to work with is of the form:

```
{
    {
        "A String",
        {
            { "xxx", "yyy", "zzz" },
            { "aaa", "bbb", "ccc" }
        },
    },
    {
        "Another String",
        {
            { "abc", "def", "ghi" },
            { "qwe", "asd", "zxc" },
            { "rty", "fgh", "vbn" }
        }
    }
}
```

I know how to organize it, but not how to express it in usable java terms that I can pass to parameterized tests.

**UPDATE**:

I did eventually puzzle it out:

```
@Parameters( name = "Test ({index}" )
public static Collection< Object[] > data()
{
    return Arrays.asList( new Object[][]
    {
        {
            "A String",
            new Object[]
            {
                new String[]{ "xxx", "yyy", "zzz" },
                new String[]{ "aaa", "bbb", "ccc" }
            },
        },
        {
            "Another String",
            new Object[]
            {
                new String[]{ "abc", "def", "ghi" },
                new String[]{ "qwe", "asd", "zxc" },
                new String[]{ "rty", "fgh", "vbn" }
            }
        }
    } );
}
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to test.

Comment: Why the downvote?  My question was not about testing.  It was, how to model the presented data. c0der understood and offered a good suggestion too.

Answer (score 1):

I am not entirely sure what you need. Wold this be appropriate ?

```
Map<String, String[][]> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("A String",new String[][] {{"xxx", "yyy", "zzz"},{"aaa","bbb","ccc"}});
```